# How set Text Align?

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I want `TextView` to end at red Line in picture below instead of start line of three blue textviews .

How ?

[image]

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:id="@+id/relative">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/progress"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Progress"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:textColor="#1A237E"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text=" absolute"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/above"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text=" percentage"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/above"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text=" goal"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/goal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/below"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/below"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />
```

thanx in advance .

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What TextView are you talking about? Do you want the three blue TextViews to end at the red vertical line?

Comment: yes that is the issue ,i want change direction of text from left to right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right align your three blue TextViews with the Progress TextView. That way, all the blue TextViews will be right aligned. Then, instead of using `layout_gravity=right`, use `gravity=right`. That will right align the text within the blue TextViews. Finally, make all the blue TextViews be `to_rightOf` textview4, which is the longest TextView. Doing these adjustments will make the layout look like this:

[image: Layout after adjustments]

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relative"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="49dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Progress"
    android:textColor="#1A237E"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=" absolute"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/above"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="18%"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=" percentage"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/above"
    android:layout_below="@+id/above"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="12.4%"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=" goal"
    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/below"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/below"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="0%"/>
```

Comment: I didn't adjust paddings, so you will have to remove the right paddings to get it completely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In your case this was different than what I normally set it up.  But in this case its easier to add

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

and then for the views you want to align to the right side add

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/holder"
```

Comment: no resources found that match layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/holder" , although id is the same in textview and view i want align with

Comment: I just noticed the looping dependency,  ok I changed it.  And you will need to remove some of the current alignments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can put those two horizontal TextView inside a 
LinearLayout and set the ***LinearLayout*** below the percentage's TextView. Doing this you can have more customizability with the alignment of the TextView.